# Abstract of talk by Wielandt required

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups

I am searching for Abstracts of short communications of the International Congress of Mathematicians, 1962. In particular, the abstract of Wielandt's talk  "Bedingungen für die Konjugiertheit von Untergruppen endlicher Gruppen" ("Conditions for the Conjugacy of Finite Groups"). Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The appropriate volume is not on the web site of the IMU, so I suspect you will have to look in a university library.

Comment: @Alexander: Good luck in your search for such an abstract! By accident I got an abstract for Verma's short contributed talk once; I think this was at the Vancouver ICM but don't know if he actually gave the talk. My only advice is to contact a student or living collaborator of Wielandt, who might have a copy of the abstract. (By the way,the translation of his title is not quite right. It should be "Conditions for the conjugacy of subgroups of finite groups".)

Comment: @Ben: Usually the texts of abstracts for short contributed talks are not incuded in the ICM proeedings, so a library might not be helpful.   The ICM website has recently been revamped, but the 1962 proceedings do include the title of Wielandt's contribution on page XVIII.

Comment: I happen to have this particular volume of the proceedings and can confirm what Jim Humphreys suggests: in the preface it says "short communications ...are not included in the proceedings... Summaries of these contributions, if received in time, were printed in Abstracts of Short Communications, issued to members during the Congress"